# discord.js bot playing audio without sound

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am using discord.js v13 and attempting to play audio files using @discordjs/voice. My problem is that the bot will do everything correctly, but when the green circle that indicates that a sound is coming from the bot appears, I don't hear anything. I don't think this is an audio issue with my headphones because I can hear everything else fine, including other people on discord.

Here is my code:

```
const { getVoiceConnection, joinVoiceChannel, AudioPlayerStatus, createAudioResource, getNextResource, createAudioPlayer, NoSubscriberBehavior } = require('@discordjs/voice');

module.exports = {
    name: "play",
    category: "music",
    description: "plays audio",
    usage: "<id | mention>",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        
        const voiceChannel =  message.member.voice.channel;
        
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: voiceChannel.id,
            guildId: message.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        });
        
        const audioPlayer = createAudioPlayer();
        connection.subscribe(audioPlayer);
        audioPlayer.play(createAudioResource('./sound/audio.mp3'));
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try writing [`console.log(createAudioResource('./sound/audio.mp3').readable)`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/audioresource.html#readable) before `audioPlayer.play(...)` to see if the audio resource is possible to play

Comment: The console displayed true on the logs

Comment: Hmm, try `createAudioResource(createReadStream('./sound/audio.mp3'), { inlineVolume: true })` (with & and if doesn't work, without the `inlineVolume : true`

Comment: that fixed the issue, thank you

Comment: Does removing inlineVolume or adding it changes anything ?

Comment: inlineVolume didn't change anything for me

Comment: Alright thanks ! I just posted an answer just approove it so that ppl will know how to fix the problem ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply writing [`createAudioResource('./sound/audio.mp3')`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/modules.html#createaudioresource) isn't the correct syntax to get the audio resource of the mp3 file you have, the only thing you miss is the [`createReadStream()`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream/) which will create a readable stream before transforming it into an audio resource. In clear, just change

```js
  audioPlayer.play(createAudioResource('./sound/audio.mp3'));
```

to

```js
  audioPlayer.play(createAudioResource(createReadStream('./sound/audio.mp3')));
```

If this still doesn't solve your answer maybe try adding options like the inlineVolume option as the second parameter:

```js
  audioPlayer.play(createAudioResource(createReadStream('./sound/audio.mp3')),
    { inlineVolume: true });
```